# Check if setOnItemClickListener is selected

Tags: java, android, arraylist, onclicklistener

I wrote a simple program that will display an ArrayList and the user can select an item and delete it with a button.

If the user does not select an item but continues to hit the delete button, they will remove the first item on the ArrayList. How do I prevent this from happening? The delete button should only run when an item is selected, so I need to find a way to check for that

```
int positionID;
ListView listview;
ArrayList<String> valuesArray = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    valuesArray.add("a");
    valuesArray.add("b");
    valuesArray.add("c");
    valuesArray.add("d");
    valuesArray.add("e");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valuesArray);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            positionID = (int) id;
        }
    });
}

public void onClickDelete(View v) {
//need to check if an item is selected. if so, run code below
    valuesArray.remove(positionID);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valuesArray);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: why you don't try setting the visibility of the deleted button, ie, if an item is selected you set the delete button visible and it will improve the user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you've provided, this is likely happening because the default initialized value for `positionID` is set to 0. To fix this, you could initialize `int positionID = -1` and then in your `onClickDelete` method, do a check to make sure the `positionID` is not invalid. Like this:

```
public void onClickDelete(View v) {
    if (positionID < 0) return;
    // continue your code here
}
```

By the way, a few other things you should fix. You should actually interact with `adapter` directly, so instead of `valuesArray.remove(positionID)` you should do `adapter.remove(positionID)`. This will automatically update the adapter and refresh the `ListView` for you so you can get rid of the last two lines of your `onClickDelete` method.

You can just make `valuesArray` a local variable in your `onCreate` method, unless you plan on manipulating it directly elsewhere in your code. If you choose to do that, you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to make the adapter refresh your `ListView`.

Comment: @D.Kate With an addition to this, You can also play with delete button's alpha values. Like I've in my project, set alpha as .2 as default in xml and then when item is selected, put it to .8 then when onClickDelete is selected set alpha back to .2. This looks great and works great.

Comment: @Brian That works, thanks!! I tried your other suggestion about the adapter but it's not global and I'm pretty new to coding still so don't know how to apply that to my code :(

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it!

Comment: No worries, If any problem occurs, I'll help.

Comment: Ah, well that's simple you can just make the `adapter` that you created in your `onCreate` an instance variable of your class just like how you did with your `valuesArray`. You should only ever use one instance of an `Adapter` with a `ListView`. A very common mistake for beginners is to create a new `Adapter` every time they want to update the list, that's very inefficient and not necessary! Likewise, let me know if you're still have trouble getting that to work.